# Integral involving trig functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int 5 (\tan(\sin(x)))^3 \cos(x)dx$$

What I did was let $\sin x=u$, then it's

$$\int 5\tan(u)^3 du$$

then I broke it up into parts

$$5\int(\tan(u))^2 \tan(u) du$$

$$5\int((\sec(u))^2-1)) \tan(u) du$$

$$5\int(\sec(u))^2(\tan(u))-\tan(u))du$$

then I let $(\sec(u))^2 = v$

$$5\int(v)dv+\ln|\cos(u)|$$

replaced the variables in terms of $x$

$$\frac{5}{2}(\sec(\sin(x)))^4 + \ln|\cos(\sin(x))|$$

This is incorrect but I do not see why. Thank you.

Comment: Type in Latex please!

Comment: I don't know it!! I am sorry!

Comment: For your second substitution, you should have let $v=\tan u$.

Comment: It has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
\int 5\tan^3\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta,\tag{1}
\end{align}
and by letting $u=\sin\left(\theta\right),\:du=\cos\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta\implies\displaystyle\frac{du}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}=d\theta$, therefore giving us
\begin{align}
5\int \tan^3\left(u\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)\frac{du}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}&=5\int\tan^3\left(u\right)\:du\tag{2},
\end{align}
and now by the common reduction of powers s. th.
\begin{align}
\int \tan^n\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta=\frac{\tan^{n-1}\left(\theta\right)}{n-1}-\int\tan^{n-2}\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta,
\end{align}
we find that
\begin{align}
5\int\tan^3\left(u\right)\:du&=5\left\{\frac{\tan^2\left(u\right)}{2}-\int\tan\left(u\right)\:du\right\}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{5\tan^2\left(u\right)}{2}-5\int\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{\cos\left(u\right)}\:du\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{5\tan^2\left(u\right)}{2}+5\log\left(\cos\left(u\right)\right)+C_1\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{5\tan^2\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{2}+5\log\left(\cos\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\right)+C_1\tag{6}.
\end{align}
Alternatively, back at $\left(2\right)$ we could instead go to
\begin{align}
5\int\tan^3\left(u\right)\:du&=5\int \tan\left(u\right)\left[\sec^2\left(u\right)-1\right]\:du\tag{7}\\
&=5\int\tan\left(u\right)\sec^2\left(u\right)\:du-5\int\tan\left(u\right)\:du\tag{8}\\
&=\frac{5\tan^2\left(u\right)}{2}+5\log\left(\cos\left(u\right)\right)+C_2,\tag{9}
\end{align}
and then by substituting back in for $u$ to get
\begin{align}
\int 5\tan^3\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta&=\frac{5\tan^2\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{2}+5\log\left(\cos\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\right)+C_2,\tag{10}
\end{align}
which is the same as $\left(6\right)$.

Comment: Thank you great sir, I have it now and understand it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed as follows (I left out the factor 5):
$$\int \tan^3 u \, du = \int \tan u (\sec^2u-1)\,  du = \int \tan u\sec^2u \, du-\int \tan u\, du$$
The last one is easy ($\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$, let $t = \cos x$) and for the first one, choose $t = \tan u$, then $dt = \sec² u \, du$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed that is incorrect because of the substitution $v=(sec\ u)^2$. If $v$ is such then $dv$ must be? $2sec\ u\cdot sec\ u\ tan\ u=2(sec\ u)^2 tan\ u$.

Looking on the integral above: $5\int (v)dv=5\int (sec\ u)^2\cdot 2(sec\ u)^2 tan\ u\not =5\int (sec\ u)^2tan\ u$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\int\tan^3x~dx=\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^3x}dx=-\int\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^3x}~d(\cos x).$